# Out of Range values in two dimensional Arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, while-loop, null

I was aware that out of range value for arrays in Ruby is nil; however I encountered an issue when I used two dimensional array. Here's a simple code to illustrate an issue I'm having.

```
a = [1]
b = [[ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4]]
puts a[0]   #outputs 1
puts b[0][0] #outputs 1
puts a[100] == nil #outputs true
puts b[100][100] == nil #undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Is there a special syntax that is required or am I missing something here?

Comment: Technically that's an array-of-arrays, there aren't any two dimensional arrays in Ruby (unless you count [`Matrix`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html)).

Comment: You can avoid the error by `b[100].to_a[100]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b[100]` is out of range so the result is nil.
You are then calling `nil[100]` which raises an error since nil does not have any `[]` method.